# Using Choice stuck with loop?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So, when running my code I get a this message:

> "The System cannot find the drive specified."

and it looks like it is looping...

```
@echo off
@title CHOICE
:menu
cls
CHOICE /c:123456789 /N /M "Enter: "
if errorlevel  6 goto MSG
if errorlevel  5 goto WORF
if errorlevel  4 goto HRF
if errorlevel  3 goto MELFI
if errorlevel  2 goto MSRR
if errorlevel  1 goto EXPRESS
goto end
:EXPRESS
    ECHO EXPRESS
    call EXPRESS.BAT
goto MENU
:MSRR
    ECHO MSRR 
    call MSRR.BAT
goto MENU
:MELFI
    ECHO MELFI
    call MELFI.BAT
goto MENU
:HRF
    ECHO HRF
    call HRF.BAT
goto MENU
:WORF
    ECHO WORF
    call WORF.BAT
goto MENU
:MSG
    ECHO MSG
    call MSG.BAT
goto MENU
@pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little trickier way to do what your code does: your problem might be in one of the batch files that you are calling.  REM out the `cls` command to see if any helpful error messages appear:

```
@echo off
title CHOICE
:menu
cls
CHOICE /c:1234567 /N /M "Enter a numeral from 1-6 (7 to quit): "

if errorlevel  1 set "routine=EXPRESS"
if errorlevel  2 set "routine=MSRR"
if errorlevel  3 set "routine=MELFI"
if errorlevel  4 set "routine=HRF"
if errorlevel  5 set "routine=WORF"
if errorlevel  6 set "routine=MSG"
if errorlevel  7 exit

echo %routine%
call "%routine%.bat"
goto :menu
```

Comment: Thanks it was something really simple, I had named the .bat file CHOICE.bat